# Cannot get instance of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, textarea

I have several fields which need to be initialized with `CKEditor`, for this I have created an helper class that contains the `initEditor` method.

The method below should return the initialized editor but it doesn't:

```
window.CKEditorHelper = window.CKEditorHelper || {};

(function (exports) {

    exports.initEditor = function (input, myEditor) {
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector(input), {
                language: {
                    ui: 'en'
                    content: 'en'
                }
            })
            .then(editor => {
                myEditor = editor;
            });
    };

})(window.CKEditorHelper);
```

this is called in the following way:

```
let editor = null;
CKEditorHelper.initEditor('#description', editor);
```

so when I click on a button:

```
$('#save').on('click', function(){
    console.log(editor.getData());
});
```

I get:

> Cannot read property 'getData' of null

what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues on your code

> let editor = null;

the **let** keyword only define a variable within function scope, when you use **editor** on another scope (your click handle event), it could be undefined

Another line

> myEditor = editor;

This just simple made the reference to your original **editor** object will gone

Here is my solution to fix it

Change the way you init an editor like bellow

```
window.editorInstance = {editor: null};
CKEditorHelper.initEditor('#description', editorInstance);
```

Change your CKEditorHelper to

```
window.CKEditorHelper = window.CKEditorHelper || {};

(function (exports) {

exports.initEditor = function (input, myEditorInstance) {
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector(input), {
            language: {
                ui: 'en'
                content: 'en'
            }
        })
        .then(editor => {
            myEditorInstance.editor = editor;
        });
};

})(window.CKEditorHelper);
```

And when you want to use your editor

```
console.log(editorInstance.editor.getData());
```

Comment: I have to await 7 hours before assign the bounty, anyway the problem is fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give this in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  CKEDITOR.replace('tmpcontent', { height: '100px' })
})
```

take the value by using following

```
$('#save').on('click', function(){
 var textareaValue = CKEDITOR.instances.tmpcontent.getData();
});
```

```html
<label class="control-label">Message</label>
<textarea name="tmpcontent" id="tmpcontent" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

//OR in latest version

```
var myEditor;

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#description' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
        myEditor = editor;
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        console.error( err.stack );
    } );
```

and then get data using

```
myEditor.getData();
```

Comment: I'm getting `CKEDITOR` is not defined, I'm using the latest version "5", this version is not accessible using `CKEDITOR` only with `ClassicEditor`. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @sfarzoso check my second solution with `ClassicEditor`

Comment: I can't find any difference with my code for the second solution, could you explain please?